# How to extract latest record

Tags: sql

I have two tables like this:-

TABLE A

```
ITEM    LOCATION    CODE
A       WHS         QW123
B       WHS         QW124
C       WHS         QW125
```

TABLE B

```
ATR_NO          ITEM    CODE    ATT_ID  ATT_VALUE
20110101123310  A   QW123   SIZE    24
20110101123310  A   QW123   GRADE   2
20110101123351  B   QW124   SIZE    20
20110101123351  B   QW124   GRADE   3
20110101124042  C   QW125   SIZE    26
20110101124042  C   QW125   GRADE   4
20110101131210  A   QW123   SIZE    26
20110101131210  A   QW123   GRADE   1
20110101144542  C   QW125   SIZE    27
20110101144542  C   QW125   GRADE   1
```

The expected results using SQL shold look like this:-

RESULT

```
ITEM    LOCATION    CODE    SIZE    GRADE
A       WHS         QW123   26  1
B       WHS         QW124   20  3
C       WHS         QW125   27  1
```

How can I achieve that ?

Comment: Where does `GRADE` come from?

Comment: How are the rows in TableB ordered?? Do you have date/time stamp on that table?? A sequential ID or something??

Comment: And even more is, if you have table B containing everything already why would you have table A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the latest ATR_NO for each item, join that with table b twice to get the size and grade:

```
select
  a.ITEM, a.LOCATION, a.CODE, SIZE = b1.ATT_VALUE, GRADE = b2.ATT_VALUE
from
  [TABLE A] a
  inner join (select max(ATR_NO) from [TABLE B] group by ITEM) i on i.ITEM = a.ITEM
  inner join [TABLE B] b1 on b1.ATR_NO = i.ATR_NO and b1.ATT_ID = 'SIZE'
  inner join [TABLE B] b2 on b2.ATR_NO = i.ATR_NO and b2.ATT_ID = 'GRADE'
order by
  a.ITEM
```

Comment: Error msg:- Error: SQL0104 - Token = was not valid. Valid tokens: + - AS <IDENTIFIER>. (State:37000, Native Code: FFFFFF98)

Comment: @Bob: What database system are you using?

Comment: I hv used this:-select
  a.ITEM, a.LOCATION, a.CODE, b.SIZE, b.GRADE
from
  [TABLE A] AS A
  left outer join (select ITEM, CODE,
                   MAX (CASE WHEN ATT_ID = 'SIZE' THEN ATT_VALUE ELSE NULL END) as SIZE,
                   MAX (CASE WHEN ATT_ID = 'GRADE' THEN ATT_VALUE ELSE NULL END) as GRADE
                   from [TABLE B] GROUP BY ITEM, CODE) As B
  on a.ITEM=b.ITEM and a.CODE=b.CODE
where a.CODE = 'QW123'

Comment: Problem is QW123. It shd report as SIZE 26 & GRADE 1 but instead, it reported as SIZE 24 & GRADE 2.

Comment: @Bob: It seems that it doesn't support that alias syntax. Use `b1.ATT_VALUE as SIZE, b2.ATT_VALUE as GRADE` instead.

Comment: @Bob: Hm... As your query picks the highest value for size and the highest value for grade instead of the size and grade for the highest ATR_NO, it should return the mismatched SIZE 26 and GRADE 2.

Comment: @Bob: Try my query with the change that I suggested. Alternatively, use the approach from the query with a subquery that gets the latest ATR_NO for each item and separate joins for the size and the grade.